User safety when touching tone controls in vacuum tube preamplifier


Images taken from: "Designing tube preamps for guitar and bass" - Merlin Blencowe. Pg-244,247. Published by author, 2009, 2nd edition.
I intend to use these circuits in a guitar preamplifier. My concern is these potentiometers are connected to high voltages (100V) and therefore are risky to operate with bare hands.
Can this circuit be made safer?
DC cannot flow because of the capacitors. I can use current limiting circuits and fuses to make it safer, however, I haven't made any high voltage circuits before, that's why I am asking this question.


My concern is these potentiometers are connected to high voltages(100V) and therefore are risky to operate with bare hands.

The incoming signal to the tone stack generally has high DC offset, yes, but it's removed by the coupling caps of each control (note that the voltage ratings of the capacitors must be at least 400V). So all the pots see low voltages across their terminals. Also, as AnalogKid mentioned, the turning shaft and the resistive element inside have a good amount of insulation. You can still use plastic knobs for further insulation, if you worry. A note here: The carbon pots you see in a valve guitar amplifier generally don't have a high voltage rating.

I haven't made any high voltage circuits before that's why I am asking this question.

In valve guitar amplifiers, an FMV (Fender-Marshall-Vox) tone stack which is the one shown in your question almost always comes after a cathode follower (you can still see the tone stack as a load of a common cathode triode amplifuer stage, just like shown in the 2nd image in your question, but not that common). The DC offset can be high but, as I stated above, it's going to be removed by the coupling caps. If you still find it unsafe then you can use a divider along with the cathode follower to reduce the voltages further:

In the config above, voltages (including relatively high DC offset) will be divided by ~100. The 100k will have high voltage across it but the tone stack will see lower voltages anyways.

Shouldn't "...almost always followed by a cathode follower"  read: "... almost always preceded by a cathode follower"?

@Theodore indeed.

With standard, full-sized potentiometers, high voltage safety is not an issue.  There is significant insulation between the potentiometer resistive element and the shaft.  Also, you can use a pot with a plastic shaft.

A simple way to deal with it is to add a transient voltage suppressor (TVS) on the potentiometer side of each DC-blocking capacitor. That way, if the coupling capacitors were to fail shorted, the TVS will activate and overload the anode resistor, causing it to fail open, all the while protecting the potentiometer from potentials more than say 50V away from case earth.
